How can i fix this problem in the picture below . Whats is wrong?
I have encountered a problem while writing in Overleaf. Could you please let me know what might be wrong. Thank you in advanced


Welcome. // Several issues: It’s hard to read. There is no error message. Shall we collectively guess? Etc. // Suggestion: skim through some other questions which were answered and understand, what we need from you to be effective. Thank you

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

In the future, please copy and paste the code you're using.  Then we can copy and paste what you've done.
